# Data assimilation to correct imagery

Tags: image-processing, kalman-filter

I am attempting to correct some imagery.

The image is a composite of different aerial images which were collected under less than ideal lighting conditions and therefore when they are mosaiced there is a noticeable difference between them i.e. a dark stripe. To resolve this I have simulated how the imagery should look - but this is just a simulation and all the interesting information is still in the original imagery.

[image]

(not the best example - but trust me it needs correcting!)

My question is how can I correct the original imagery with the simulated imagery? I was thinking that a data assimilation technique may be the go but have little experience with this e.g. using a 2d ensemble kalman filter.

I would ideally be able to do this in R or Python.

---- EDIT ----

Here is a larger scene that highlights the issue more clearly. I haven't generated the simulation for this area yet.

[image]

Comment: Please provide other samples. This doesn't show the problem.

Comment: could _histogram equalization_ help you?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have added a larger example

Comment: @VC.One: equalization is a global operation and will apply the same effect everywhere. So the differences in intensity will remain. You need something more adaptive. And there is no reason to stretch the contrast.

Comment: I am curious to know why you don't distinguish the mosaic edges; the tiles use to be quadrilateral, so you expect straigth (or slightly curved) edges.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't have the original underlying imagery so don't have the extents of the flight lines.  As far as I am aware, the original imagery was captured with a "push-broom" camera and therefore nice frames weren't captured.

Answer (score 2):

I see this as aproblem of shading correction. The image has been "corrupted" by an uneven light field and should be "flattened".

But you don't know the illumination field and you need to somehow reconstruct it. You essentially achieve that by lowpass filtering the image (Gaussian, median, bilateral...).

Then apply multiplicative correction. The images below illustrate the process.

**Source image**

[image]

**Smoothed illumination field**

[image]

**Corrected**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The paper

BROWN, Matthew; LOWE, David G. Automatic panoramic image stitching using invariant features. *International journal of computer vision*, 2007, 74.1: 59-73.

has section 6 about "Gain Compensation" and section 7 about "Multi-Band Blending"; maybe they can be applied to your problem?

The following is Figure 5 from the above paper:

[image]

OpenCV 3.1 has some support for [Exposure Compensation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/dff/group__stitching__exposure.html#gsc.tab=0) and [Image Blenders](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d46/group__stitching__blend.html#gsc.tab=0.).